# gearman is returning old worker results

Tags: php, ubuntu, gearman, worker, supervisord

I have a PHP gearman client and worker. I am testing my worker with very minimal output to ensure all is working as intended. Strangely, I am getting old results from previous workers and I can't figure out why. It seems that they cycle through in order of creation so it's as if they still exist somewhere, somehow.

I have killed all gearman processes using `killall gearmand` and then verified no connections are running by `netstat -plnt` in terminal. I've even restarted the whole box but nothing is killing off these old workers it seems.

As a side note, I'm using `Supervisord` to load the worker via terminal and killing that process by removing the socket (`unlink /tmp/supervisor.sock`).

Anyone have a hint? I don't know where else to look.

Comment: Try http://serverfault.com/ or http://superuser.com/

Comment: if a restart of your *machine* doesn't clear the old results then the results are being persisted, or your diagnosis is wrong. It certainly is not a `supervisord` problem.

Comment: maybe you're using persistent Gearman queue? :)